# 2 outlets in kitchen have no power to them

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have two outlets in my kitchen that have no power to them. I didn't change plugs because there is no power to them. I checked breakers and there is power coming out. I checked  bus bar and made sure wire was secure. I don't know what to do next?

Comment: Are they protected outlets, aka  GFCI (Ground Fault Circuit Interrupters)?  They are the type that usually have two little buttons, one with "test" and the other "reset."

Comment: The GFCI that protects them could even be in an adjacent room, although that is not common in a kitchen.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like they're protected by a ground-fault circuit interrupter (GFCI), and the GFCI has tripped. You'll want to start by searching for the GFCI device, and resetting it. In most cases, it will look like a receptacle, except that there will be two button in the center of the face.  Press the *RESET* button in as far as it will go, you may or may not hear a click.

If these receptacles are not GFCI protected, then there's likely a loose, broken, or damaged wire somewhere.  You'll have to determine everything that's on the circuit, then try and figure out where the line feeding the first dead receptacle comes from.  With the circuit breaker off, carefully inspect the wiring of all the devices on the circuit.  Look for damaged, loose, or broken connections.

If you're not comfortable with electrical work, or don't have the knowledge and tools necessary, please contact a local licensed electrician.